# Help Me unlock her phone

Tags: password

She knows all my passwords and when I asked her what is your mobile password (pattern), she gave me a chit which was exactly:

> it was neVer your password

Can someone help me unlock her phone? It is that standard mobile nine dot pattern lock which almost every phone has!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After John's answer.

> It is 2-3-5-4-8 . Count the number of letters per word. 
> There is one more thing: 2+3+5+4+8=22 and the 22nd letter is 'V' .  That's why it is only in capital case.

Comment: So what was the pattern? These are just the numbers?

Comment: @ahmed Imagine all dots 9 got a number like old keypad phone.

Answer (score 5):

Is it:

> 2-3-5-4-8. 
>  Count the ol number of letters?

Comment: Very close to a perfect answer . Well done .

Comment: But why only letter 'V' is in capital case .

Answer (score 4):

Is it:

> 1004. M (title), I and V are all incorrectly cased, MIV=1004 in Roman numerals.

Comment: It's a pattern lock password. May be password made confusion I edited it.

Comment: >!Yeah I did it intentionally , you cracked one of two password , now here is a hidden pattern lock help me find that. You see real lock lies inside chit.

Comment: Why not include W and S also which are incorrectly cased too?

Comment: @SamRoy; not true!

Comment: It was true. The post has just been edited (after my comment). Earlier it was "& When" instead of "and when", and ", She" instead of ", she" @JMP; and you only edited that !!

Comment: @SamRoy Sorry for that . Now question has been edited thanks to JMP.

Answer (score 3):

Is it:

> 183   Literally just the 'V' pattern on the nine-dot entry pad?
>
>
> `.   .   . 
> . \ . / . 
> .   .   .`

Comment: Hmm! But ' V ' can be drawn by different ways , like 183 , 381 486 ,684 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> 74869351.
>  You did say M, I, V is intentional.
>  If you draw it out then you get the sequence

Comment: >! I also said answer lies within chit. Chit is in yellow colour.